# How to pull out Pikachu's D-tilt into jab lock consistently?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've been reading and watching how to *jab lock* with pikachu. I'm especially interested with the *D-tilt* into *jab lock* but I'm not able to pull it out consistently.

The problem I have is that after the *D-tilt*, and the enemy failing the tech, I need to run to get in jab range. When I stop running the **stopping animation prevents me from using my jab** in time so I end up using the *dash atack* mostly.

[Here's a thread specifically talking about pikachu's jab lock options](https://smashboards.com/threads/pikachus-jab-lock-setups-guide.386613/) but they are obviating the point I'm struggling with (the same happens with all tutorials about it, which makes me think I'm just messing up the timing or some basic stuff I overlooked).

Is there any way to avoid stopping animation? Which is the right input sequence to pull out this jab lock consistently (from the D-tilt to the jab)?

Comment: That thread mentions d-tilt to jab lock only works at or above 100%. Are you trying it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured that if there was anyone to turn to for advice, it would be arguably the world's best Pikachu player, ESAM. The guy posts tutorials and guides on his YouTube for all things Pikachu, and [this video](https://youtu.be/qg8PrI5a6L0?t=5m43s) should show you what to do!

When the enemy is at around 90-100%, D-tilt will force a tech situation. If the enemy misses that tech, you have the opportunity to run up and begin a jab lock. You can only jab 3 times before a neutral get-up is forced on the enemy, so after your third jab, perform your smash attack of choice.

ESAM does mention that this technique stops working at around 110%, as d-tilt begins to send the enemy too far, allowing for adequate time to time  a tech or perform a get-up attack.

Practice makes perfect, and although I don't play Pikachu, hitting the lab (as they say!) is the best way to learn!

Comment: Running and stopping right in time to perform a jab had never been so hard for me so I guessed I was doing something wrong. Here we go, hitting the lab again!

Comment: @Grirg You may want to practice your escape options from that kind of set up as well. Someone well versed in the Pikachu matchup might be waiting for that d-tilt to force a tech, and may be ready with a punish on get-up.